# Export SharePoint 2013 list big data to Excel

Tags: sharepoint-designer, excel, splistitem, sharepoint-list, export-to-excel

I have a SharePoint list with 13879 items, so when I am trying to export the list to Excel, data doesn't export.

It is blank sheet and looks like this. (where column1, column2... are SharePoint list column names).

[image]

Also list view threshold is increased to 15000.
Here is an image of list settings showing list view threshold:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that Excel connects with the same credentials you use when browsing your list? Excel will try to use credentials from IE (regardless of your default or preferred browser). If IE is not authentified to your SharePoint site, then it will prompt for authentication.

Comment: oh, thank you it was because of credentials difference

Comment: but now it exports part of list data, not whole data :(

Comment: You should probably edit your question or even better ask a new one. How much data is exported? do you see any pattern differentiating the rows exported from the ones that are not exported?

Comment: Problem is because the data import into Excel will Time-Out.

Comment: to avoid the timeout try to use the query outside of the heavy usage time (ie after hours) or request admins to increase the timeout settings for the application.